# C write number digits, one by one and in extension, in a new line

Tags: c

I'm new in C and I can't do a simple exercise for school.

I want to do something like this:

```
 Please insert a number: 12345
 five
 four
 three
 two
 one
```

Basically, the user inputs a number and them the program writes, in a new line, the number from the last significant number to the most.

This is to do with the switch function and only basic programming skills.

I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num; printf("Please insert a number: "); scanf("%d", &num);
    switch(num){
    case 1:printf("One\n");break;
    case 2:printf("Two\n");break;
    case 3:printf("Three\n");break;
    case 4:printf("Four\n");break;
    case 5:printf("Five\n");break;
    case 6:printf("Six\n");break;
    case 7:printf("Seven\n");break;
    case 8:printf("Eight\n");break;
    case 9:printf("Nine\n");break;
    case 0:printf("Zero\n");break;
    }
}
```

I I use a number between 0 and 9 it works ok but a number bigger then that it does not do nothing.

The first problem i cant solve is to, in a number, get the digit position.
I believe that In my code, the break isn't doing nothing...

Sorry if I can't explain me better but English is not my native language.

Regards,

Favolas

############################## In Progress Solution (does not work if number % 10 gives 0¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num; printf("Please insert a number: "); scanf("%d", &num);
    int i,digit;
    for (i = 0; num%10!=0;i++){
        digit = num % 10;
        switch(num){
        case 1:printf("One\n");break;
        case 2:printf("Two\n");break;
        case 3:printf("Three\n");break;
        case 4:printf("Four\n");break;
        case 5:printf("Five\n");break;
        case 6:printf("Six\n");break;
        case 7:printf("Seven\n");break;
        case 8:printf("Eight\n");break;
        case 9:printf("Nine\n");break;
        case 0:printf("Zero\n");break;
        }
        num = num / 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a well worded question

Comment: Your so-called solution is a wrong solution. What happens if the number is 666 or 1000?

Comment: Ok.  Found the error. Thanks. Will try to fix that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number `123` is `100 + 20 + 3` or `1*10^2 + 2*10^1 + 3*10^0`.

You need to isolate the individual digits from the input.

Hint: use the `/` and `%` operators

```
 12345 % 10 ==> 5
 12345 / 10 ==> 1234

 1234 % 10 ==> 4
 1234 / 10 ==> 123

 123 ... ... ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you enter a bigger number, `num` holds exactly that number, i.e. none of your cases (`0` to `9`) matches the value of `num`.

So you have to "traverse" the number digit by digit. You can extract the last digit if you take modulo 10: `12345 % 10 == 5`. Moreover, you can cut off the last digit by dividing by 10: `2345 / 10 == 234` (due to integral division).

So, you have to write a loop that extract the single digits from `num` and then apply your case distinction for each digit.

Answer (score 0):

In base 10, the number `12345` is in fact `1 * 10000 + 2 * 1000 + 3 * 100 + 4 * 10 + 5 * 1`. So you can get the last digit of a number by computing the remainder of the division of the number by `10`. And the dividend will be the most significant par of the number. So, '12345 = 1234 * 10 + 5`. In`C`, the`%`operator is used to compute the remainder of the division, so`12345 % 10`is equal to`5`.

Then, you just have to loop while the number is non-zero, taking the remainder at each step, displaying the digit and then dividing the number.

Answer (score -1):

```
void main (void){  
    int num;  
    int factor=10;  
    printf("Please insert a number: "); scanf("%d", &num);  
    while(num>0){  
        switch(num%factor){  
            case 1:printf("One\n");break;  
            case 2:printf("Two\n");break;   
            case 3:printf("Three\n");break;  
            case 4:printf("Four\n");break;  
            case 5:printf("Five\n");break;  
            case 6:printf("Six\n");break;   
            case 7:printf("Seven\n");break;  
            case 8:printf("Eight\n");break;  
            case 9:printf("Nine\n");break;  
            case 0:printf("Zero\n");break;  
        }  
        num=num/factor;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: As the question is tagged `Homework` please consider not giving the code out so much as providing pointers to help the questioner write the code.

Comment: By the way, what if the user enters the number `0`?

Comment: -1: If you are going to write code for homework questions, at least write good code so the student learns something even by just copying: `main` should return `int`; output is line buffered by default so you should terminate the string with a line break or `fflush(stdout);` after printing; `scanf` return value should be checked; you missed a validation for num <= 0; and there's no default case for the switch. Also you use very little whitespace.